# How to use regex for this expression (e.g "6.81E+10")?

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector of strings and I just want to extract those values that take the form

1. "[digit][.][digit][digit][E][+][digit][digit]" or
2. "[digit][.][digit][digit][E][+][digit][digit][digit]"

An example would be:

1. "6.81E+10" and
2. "5.01E+110"

Let the vector `a` be as follows:

```
a<-c("1.23E+110",
"1.77E+12",
"11.22E+110",
"1.222E+110",
"1.22E+1",
"1.22E+1888",
"1..72E+18",
"1.23EE+18",
"1.27E++18",
"1.27E+E+18",
"1.27R+180")
```

My command is:

`grep("^[[:digit:]]{1}[.]{1}[[:digit:]]{2}[E+]{1}[[:digit:]]{2,3}",a,value=TRUE)`

I would like it to return:

`[1] "1.23E+110" "1.77E+12"`

But instead it returns: `character(0)`

Why can't it work?

Comment: Use `grep("^[0-9]{1}\\.[0-9]{2}E\\+[0-9]{2,3}$", a)`

Comment: separare the `E` and `+`

Comment: Or `grep("^\\d[.]\\d{2}E[+]\\d{2,3}$", a, value=TRUE)` for that matter

Comment: @Zach Alright so I shall replace `[[:digit:]]` with `[0-9]` and use `\\.` and `\\+` instead of `[.]` and `[+]`. Any reasons why mine wouldn't work? Thanks!

Comment: @SymbolixAU I tried `grep("^[[:digit:]]{1}[.]{1}[[:digit:]]{2}[E]{1}[+]{1}[[:digit:]]{2,3}",a,value=TRUE)` based on your suggestion. However, it also returns `"1.22E+1888"` which I want to exclude too. Do you know why? Thanks!

Comment: You need the `$` at the end as per @thelatemail 's suggestion. Also, `+` is a reserved operator in regex.

Comment: @thelatemail Wow, this works too. But I still don't understand why mine wouldn't work?

Comment: the `$` is the anchor to the end of the line. the `1.22E+1888` is returned in your example because it successfully matched `1.22E+188`, but didn't know it had to stop there

Comment: Okay thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: yours doesn't work because of the `[E+]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue arises because of the `[E+]` line. This is saying "E or +", so you are telling it to look for either `E` or `+`

Also, the `+` on its own means "1 or more", so to search for the "+" character you need to escape it, either with `\\+` or using a string literal `[+]`

You also need the end of line anchor `$` at the end of the regex, so it knows that the last {2 or 3} digits also need to be at the end of the string.

The immediate fix to your suggested solution is

```
grep("^[[:digit:]]{1}[.]{1}[[:digit:]]{2}[E][+][[:digit:]]{2,3}$",a, value = T)
# [1] "1.23E+110" "1.77E+12"
```

But, as others have suggested (in particular @thelatemail), a neater approach is

```
grep("^\\d[.]\\d{2}E[+]\\d{2,3}$", a, value=TRUE)
```

where `\\d` is short for `[:digit:]`

Answer (score 2):

/[E+]/ matches either "E" or "+", but not "E+". /x{1}/ is redundant, equivalent to /x/. Without "$" at the end to mark the string's end, any trailing chars after the number are allowed. /[[:digit:]]/ is the same as /[0-9]/ or /\d/.

Simplify the regex to /^\d.\d\dE+\d{2,3}$/, doubling \ to \ for string escape.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have a somewhat complex regex (well, many things to match), I'm going to advocate using the `rex` package. It's really very handy for writing out these longer `regex` patterns in a more readable format using substituted shortcuts and `R` syntax:

```r
a <- c("1.23E+110",
       "1.77E+12",
       "11.22E+110",
       "1.222E+110",
       "1.22E+1",
       "1.22E+1888",
       "1..72E+18",
       "1.23EE+18",
       "1.27E++18",
       "1.27E+E+18",
       "1.27R+180")

regPat <- rex::rex(start, 
                   n_times(digit, 1), 
                   n_times(dot, 1),
                   n_times(digit, 2),
                   n_times("E+", 1),
                   between(digit, 2, 3),
                   end)

regPat
#> ^(?:[[:digit:]]){1}(?:\.){1}(?:[[:digit:]]){2}(?:E\+){1}(?:[[:digit:]]){2,3}$
```

or, if the `{1}` values aren't going to change (as per comment)...

```r
regPat <- rex::rex(start, 
                   digit, 
                   dot,
                   n_times(digit, 2),
                   "E+",
                   between(digit, 2, 3),
                   end)

regPat
#> ^[[:digit:]]\.(?:[[:digit:]]){2}E\+(?:[[:digit:]]){2,3}$

grep(regPat, a, value = TRUE)
#> [1] "1.23E+110" "1.77E+12"
```

Comment: Surely `n_times(digit, 1)` etc could be replaced with just `digit` ? Like `rex(start, digit, dot, n_times(digit, 2), "E+", between(digit, 2, 3),end)`

Comment: Sure, but I was trying to replicate the original command as faithfully as possible, and it has `{1}`s. Either way, it's substantially more readable this way.